# How to secure a Google Cloud Function with API Gateway and CORS?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-api-gateway

I created an API Gateway which uses the `x-google-backend` to a cloud functions.

When I tried to access it via browser **I received a CORS error** so I researched and find a solution by adding this to the OpenAPI config where the `address` part is the same as the cloud function.

```
options:
  operationId: cors
  x-google-backend:
    address: https://europe-west3-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/api/query
  responses:
    '200':
      description: A successful response
```

This works! So I removed the public access to the cloud function and gave the gateway service account access to it and tried again.

**Which gave me a permission error**. After research I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66716103/securing-cloud-function-using-api-gateway) explaining the problem and giving me a solution to fix it.
The issue was that I call my define the cloud function with an additional path to call `query`. I added this to the OpenAPI config:

`jwt_audience: https://europe-west3-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/api`

So I tried it again in Postman and it works, however in the browser **I now get again a CORS error.**

So now I am at square one... what should I do?
Here is my complete OpenAPI config:

```
# openapi2-functions.yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /query:
    post:
      operationId: api
      parameters:
        - in: "body"
          name: "message"
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/messasge'
      x-google-backend:
         address: https://europe-west3-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/api/query
         jwt_audience: https://europe-west3-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/api
           x-google-quota:
            metricCosts:
          "read-requests": 1
      security:
        - api_key: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
    options:
      operationId: cors
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://europe-west3-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/api/query
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
securityDefinitions:
 # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
x-google-management:
  metrics:
    # Define a metric for read requests.
    - name: "read-requests"
      displayName: "Read requests"
      valueType: INT64
      metricKind: DELTA
  quota:
    limits:
     # Define the limit or the read-requests metric.
      - name: "read-limit"
        metric: "read-requests"
        unit: "1/min/{project}"
        values:
          STANDARD: 100

definitions:
  chatmessage:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        description: session id
        example: "2vr34524tg3"
      query:
        type: string
        description: message 
        example: "Hello"
    required:
      - id
      - query
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#limitations) Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on Cloud Functions has some limitations:

> CORS preflight requests are sent without an `Authorization` header, so they will be rejected on all non-public HTTP Functions. Because the preflight requests fail, the main request will also fail.

To overcome this limitation in your case the mentioned documentation recommends to deploy a [Cloud Endpoints proxy](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#using_cloud_endpoints_to_handle_cors) and [enable CORS](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-proxy-startup-options#adding_cors_support_to_esp). Also you might find useful the [Support CORS documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/support-cors) for a description of available CORS support options